# Android Studio Emulator not launching with message "Emulator: Warning: Unable to open default EUDC font: "EUDC.TTE" ((null):0, (null))"

Tags: android

I already have virtualization technology turned on, Intel x86 Emulator Accelerator also installed.

This is the error message I'm getting:

```
Emulator: Warning: Unable to open default EUDC font: "EUDC.TTE" ((null):0, (null))
Emulator: Process finished with exit code 0
```

Comment: Same issue here on Windows 10. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 2):

The warning is not related to any problem you're having with the emulator. It's just saying that Windows support for rendering private use characters isn't configured in any kind of sensible way. Since most people don't use private use characters, this is common and can be ignored unless you actually have a need for rendering private use characters.

Comment: I have a related error in VS Code debugging Python files. The exact message is `qt.qpa.fonts: Unable to open default EUDC font: "C:\\Windows\\FONTS\\EUDC.TTE"`, so maybe related to [QT platform abstraction layer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qpa.html). Found [this](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/intl/eudc). I wonder why an application which might not have a need to render private chars insists on telling users it wouldn't be able if it were requested?